# retain isolatedstorage after application gets upgrade

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm new to Windows phone 7 development. Please clarify me whether the datas stored in isolatedstorage will get deleted once the application is upgrade to latest version. I know the datas will be deleted once the application is uninstalled. But now i need to retain the datas even after the up-gradation of latest version.  Thanks in Advance for those who clarifies my doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating an app does NOT delete its data in isolated storage.